# Submit my app on the AppExchange

Tags: appexchange, home-page-component

I am using "**Home page component**" and "**custom link**" in our app to perform In-line validation on the standard detail page. On the in-line validation process we append custom link through javaScript on the standard detail page. On click of this link we make REST API callout to validate data from third party server.

Home page components and Custom links currently not supported in Salesforce Lightning. Thus it was not visible on the salesforce Lightning.

I want to put my app on the AppExchange. Is this Home page component cause issue to put my app on AppExchange ?

Can I get Lightning Ready Certificate for my App?

Comment: This seems doubtful as Home page components and Custom link are for classic only and have limited capabilities now. You app will not be lightning ready.

Comment: Is there any way to implement Home page component and Custom link in lightning